# Is there a way to get the specific statement that caused failure when using the "with" clause in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

What I am trying to find is that if there is a way to identify the specific assert that caused the error when the asserts are inside a "with".

Ideally, I would like to see the same specific result for both tests.

The result of a given test is:

```
Condition not satisfied:

testInstance.with { trueParam falseParam }
|            |
|            false
SpockSpec$TestMe@1cf4af1e

    at SpockSpec.Does not provides specific failure(SpockSpec.groovy:10)


Condition not satisfied:

testInstance.falseParam     // expected to fail
|            |
|            false
SpockSpec$TestMe@24c2ffbc

    at SpockSpec.Provides specific failure(SpockSpec.groovy:19)
```

Code:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@Unroll
class SpockSpec extends Specification {
    def testInstance = new TestMe(trueParam: true, falseParam: false)

    def "Does not provides specific failure"() {
        expect:
        testInstance.with {
            trueParam
            falseParam
        }
    }

    def "Provides specific failure"() {
        expect:
        testInstance.trueParam
        testInstance.falseParam     // expected to fail
    }

    class TestMe {
        boolean trueParam, falseParam
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
def "Does not provides specific failure"() {
    expect:
    with( testInstance ) {
        trueParam
        falseParam
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Do you have a link where this behavior is described.

Comment: Interestingly this only works for Groovy classes.  Getting an error with a Java class.  Will have to build a different sample.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-1.8/spock-core/src/main/java/spock/lang/Specification.java#L179) you are looking for. @PranavShah

Comment: It should work for any class, not just Groovy classes.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser  I don't know what I was doing earlier, but now it does work.